# Accessing elements of a Dictionary in Java where values are lists

Tags: java, list, dictionary

In python we can construct a dictionary like `students = {name1:[marks1,marks2], name2:[marks1,marks2]}`

To fill up the marks we can do

`students[name1][0]=50, students[name1][1]=100` to get `students={name1:[50,100]}`

How can I do the same in Java? I am pretty new to java

Comment: Read about [`Map`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Multimap` from [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) for this purposes:

```
Multimap <String, Integer> students = ArrayListMultimap<String, Integer>.create();
students.put(name1, mark1);
students.put(name1, mark2);
students.put(name2, mark3);
students.put(name2, mark4);
Collection <Integer> marks1 = students.get (name1);
Collection <Integer> marks2 = students.get (name2);
```

You can do anything you want with this `Collection`, for example:

```
double avg = 0;
for (Integer mark : marks1)
    avg += mark;
avg /= marks1.size();
```

If you're not okay with doing things with `Collection`, you may use less generalized code with getting the `List<Integer>`:

```
ListMultimap <String, Integer> students = ArrayListMultimap<String, Integer>.create();
//...
List <Integer> marks1 = students.get(name1);
//...
```

Comment: Collection <Integer> marks1 = students.get (name1) will return me both marks right?

Comment: @VeilEclipse yep, it will return `Collection` consisting of two `Integer`s: `mark1` and `mark2`

Comment: From `Collection`, Could you also like tell me how can I get the individual marks for using them in different operations

Comment: @VeilEclipse `Collection<Integer>` is an iterable general interface, which `Set`, `List` and other collection interfaces extend and `HashSet`, `ArrayList` implement. You can iterate over any collection in a `for each` loop, e.g. `for (Integer mark: marks) {`. Because of constructing it as `ListMultimap` in this case it is a list with all the marks for the given student, so you could cast it to a `List` and access elements by index if you need. Multimap is pretty much a wrapper around the `Map<K, List<T>>`.

Comment: I tried `Multimap <String, Integer> students = new ListMultimap<>();`
But Eclipse asks me to cast it as
`(Multimap<String, Integer>) new ListMultimap<>();`
But it still throws error `cannot instantiate the type ListMultiMap`

Could you guide me here

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that using `Map` like.

```
 Map<String, List<Integer>> students=...
```

Here, `String` is for Student name and `List<Integer>` for marks. Now, to put value apply following logic

```
 List<Integer> marks= students.get(name1);
 if(marks==null){
   marks = new ArrayList<>();
 }
 students.put(name1, marks.add(mark));
```

Comment: Basically I am receiving the marks as
`student1 mark1,
student1 mark1,
student1 mark2,
student2 mark2`.
I am not receiving the marks as `student1 mark1 mark2`, `student1 mark1 mark2`